# JavaScript Error Finding the error on why my qty of items *cost of items won't give me a final answer

Tags: javascript

Can Someone help me? so my code allows me to send out an alert box when I run my system; first name, last name, street address, city, state, zip, something you want to buy and some type of amount. It runs but then it doesn't display the final amount of the (qty* cost of the item) at the end.
Am I missing something? how can I get it working?
Once I have the website I have no error, when I run it and it reaches the end I receive an error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null) this line 
     `if (document.getElementById("txtPurchase").value= "Gameboy"){`
and `<p><input type="button" value="Go!" name="btnSubmit" onclick="ordering()" ></p>`

(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at ordering (line:35)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (line:85)
ordering (line:35)
onclick (line:85)

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title> Confirmations on orders</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ordering() {
      var firstName;
      firstName = document.practiceForm.txtFirstName.value;
      alert(firstName);
      var lastName;
      lastName = document.practiceForm.txtLastName.value;
      alert(lastName);
      var streetAddress;
      streetAddress = document.practiceForm.txtStreetAddress.value;
      alert(streetAddress);
      var city;
      city = document.practiceForm.txtCity.value;
      alert(city);
      var state;
      state = document.practiceForm.txtState.value;
      alert(state);
      var zip;
      zip = document.practiceForm.txtZip.value;
      alert(zip);

      if (document.getElementById("txtPurchase").value = "Gameboy") {
        var gameboyPrice = 25;
        var gameboyQuantity = document.getElementsById("quantity").value;
        var gameboyTotal = gameboyPrice * gameboyQuantity;
        alert("total: $" + gameboyTotal);

      } else if (document.getElementById("txtPurchase").value = "DSI") {
        var dsiPrice = 50;
        var dsiQuantity = document.getElementsById("quantity").value;
        var dsiTotal = dsiPrice * dsiQuantity;
        alert("total: $" + dsiTotal);

      } else if (document.getElementById("txtPurchase").value = "WII") {
        var wiiPrice = 75;
        var wiiQuantity = document.getElementsById("quantity").value;
        var wiiTotal = wiiPrice * wiiQuantity;
        alert("total: $" + wiiTotal);
      }
    }
  </script>

  <form name="practiceForm">
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="txtFirstName"></p>

    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="txtLastName"></p>

    <p>Street Address: <input type="text" name="txtStreetAddress"></p>

    <p>City: <input type="text" name="txtCity"></p>

    <p>State: <input type="text" name="txtState"></p>

    <p>Zip: <input type="text" name="txtZip"></p>

    <p>What do you want to purchase today?:

      <select id="txtPurchase">
  <option value="Gameboy">Gameboy $25 each</option>
        <option value="DSI">DSI $50 each</option>
  <option value="WII">Wii $75 each</option> 
  </select>

    </p>

    <p>How much would you like to buy?: <input type="number" id="quantity"></p>

    <p><input type="button" value="Go!" name="btnSubmit" onclick="ordering()"></p>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `var dsiQuantity=document.getElementsById("quantity").value;` you have a typo mistake here. Change it to `var dsiQuantity=document.getElementById("quantity").value;`

Comment: There is also a typo here: `if (document.getElementById("txtPurchase").value= "Gameboy")` you're doing an assignment, not a comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `==` instead of `=` in if conditions

And

In one place you use `getElementsById("quantity")`
Instead use `getElementById("quantity")`     //No 's'

So your `script` tag should look like

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title> Confirmations on orders</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ordering() {
      var firstName;
      firstName = document.practiceForm.txtFirstName.value;
      alert(firstName);
      var lastName;
      lastName = document.practiceForm.txtLastName.value;
      alert(lastName);
      var streetAddress;
      streetAddress = document.practiceForm.txtStreetAddress.value;
      alert(streetAddress);
      var city;
      city = document.practiceForm.txtCity.value;
      alert(city);
      var state;
      state = document.practiceForm.txtState.value;
      alert(state);
      var zip;
      zip = document.practiceForm.txtZip.value;
      alert(zip);
      if (document.getElementById("txtPurchase").value == "Gameboy") {
        var gameboyPrice = 25;
        var gameboyQuantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        var gameboyTotal = gameboyPrice * gameboyQuantity;
        alert("total: $" + gameboyTotal);

      } else if (document.getElementById("txtPurchase").value == "DSI") {
        var dsiPrice = 50;
        var dsiQuantity = document.getElementsById("quantity").value;
        var dsiTotal = dsiPrice * dsiQuantity;
        alert("total: $" + dsiTotal);

      } else if (document.getElementById("txtPurchase").value == "WII") {
        var wiiPrice = 75;
        var wiiQuantity = document.getElementsById("quantity").value;
        var wiiTotal = wiiPrice * wiiQuantity;
        alert("total: $" + wiiTotal);
      }
    }
  </script>

  <form name="practiceForm">
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="txtFirstName"></p>

    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="txtLastName"></p>

    <p>Street Address: <input type="text" name="txtStreetAddress"></p>

    <p>City: <input type="text" name="txtCity"></p>

    <p>State: <input type="text" name="txtState"></p>

    <p>Zip: <input type="text" name="txtZip"></p>

    <p>What do you want to purchase today?:

      <select id="txtPurchase">
     <option value="Gameboy">Gameboy $25 each</option>
       <option value="DSI">DSI $50 each</option>
     <option value="WII">Wii $75 each</option> 
   </select>

    </p>

    <p>How much would you like to buy?: <input type="number" id="quantity"></p>

    <p><input type="button" value="Go!" name="btnSubmit" onclick="ordering()"></p>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Really? `if(document.getElementById("txtPurchase").value = "DSI")` this is the right answer? I dont think so

Comment: And `document.getElementById("txtPurchase").value` is redundant here. A GOOD programmer will not write something like this as an answer. Your code formatting is really messed up.

Comment: Oops! I mentioned that in my answer... but forget to correct in code.. Though I edited the answer. Btw thanks for pointing

Answer (score 0):

```
var dsiQuantity=document.getElementsById("quantity").value;
```

you have a typo mistake here. Change it to

```
var dsiQuantity=document.getElementById("quantity").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to change 
1. in if condition - put == in place of =
2. for numeric value you need to parse them into proper number (i.e. int or float)

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title> Confirmations on orders</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ordering() {
  var firstName;
  firstName = document.practiceForm.txtFirstName.value;
  console.log(firstName);
  var lastName;
  lastName = document.practiceForm.txtLastName.value;
  console.log(lastName);
  var streetAddress;
  streetAddress = document.practiceForm.txtStreetAddress.value;
  console.log(streetAddress);
  var city;
  city = document.practiceForm.txtCity.value;
  console.log(city);
  var state;
  state = document.practiceForm.txtState.value;
  console.log(state);
  var zip;
  zip = document.practiceForm.txtZip.value;
  console.log(zip);

  var purchase = document.getElementById("txtPurchase").value;
   // parse value in Float type data.
  var qty = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quantity").value);

  // USE == for comparison
  if (purchase == "Gameboy") {
    var gameboyPrice = 25;
    var gameboyTotal = gameboyPrice * qty;
    alert("total: $" + gameboyTotal);

  } else if (purchase == "DSI") {
     var dsiPrice = 50;
     var dsiTotal = dsiPrice * qty;
     alert("total: $" + dsiTotal);

   } else if (purchase == "WII") {
     var wiiPrice = 75;
     var wiiTotal = wiiPrice * qty;
     alert("total: $" + wiiTotal);
   }
 }
</script>

<form name="practiceForm">
  <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="txtFirstName"></p>
  <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="txtLastName"></p>
  <p>Street Address: <input type="text" name="txtStreetAddress"></p>
  <p>City: <input type="text" name="txtCity"></p>
  <p>State: <input type="text" name="txtState"></p>
  <p>Zip: <input type="text" name="txtZip"></p>

  <p>What do you want to purchase today?:
   <select id="txtPurchase">
     <option value="Gameboy">Gameboy $25 each</option>
     <option value="DSI">DSI $50 each</option>
     <option value="WII">Wii $75 each</option> 
  </select>
 </p>

 <p>How much would you like to buy?: <input type="number" id="quantity"></p>
 <p><input type="button" value="Go!" name="btnSubmit" onclick="ordering()">
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```